# AWSCognito -> defaultServiceConfiguration is nil

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, amazon-cognito

I am trying to use `AWS` `Cognito` in an iOS app, for user authentication, I have the following kind of code (the keys are garbage):

```
let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast1,
                                                        identityPoolId: "us-east-1_XXXYYYZZZ"),
serviceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1,
                                               credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider),
configuration = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration(clientId: "ahdlahlfkahdlsfhldhafiaf",
                                                        clientSecret: "gf79gsgs08g9fg897",
                                                        poolId: "us-east-1_XXXYYYZZZ")

AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.registerCognitoIdentityUserPool(with: configuration, forKey: "UserPool")
......
```

On the last line (*AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.registerCognitoIdentityUserPool*), I get this error message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: '`defaultServiceConfiguration` is `nil`. You need to set it before using this method.'
```

After searching the net, and reading it is probably a *.plist* problem, I have set up my *info.plist* in a few various ways, but whatever I do I keep getting the same error message.

What am I supposed to do about *defaultServiceConfiguration* ?
Any relevant tip would be greatly appreciated.

I need to say that my experience with `AWSCognito` is rather limited, so I may well be doing wrong some basic settings or coding.

Comment: Try using the other `register` method: `AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.register(with: serviceConfiguration, userPoolConfiguration: configuration, forKey: "yourKey")`

Comment: I was able to move forward by using : AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: nil)